# What is the best way to check the correct work of subdirectory rails production application before update in the production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I have the production application in the server in a subdirectory like `www.server.cl/myapp`.

But when I am in the development enviroment (running `rails server`) the application run on `localhost:3000` and I can not check if the routes are 100% correct in the production enviroment (subdirectory) especially the assets paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `staging` environment (similar or identical to production environment) and deploy and test in this environment before deploy to `production` environment.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_site) is more detail description.

Comment: but what about subdirectory?

Comment: Check what it works in staging environment, then deploy changes to production.